# How do I improve the graphics for videos and 3D uses?

Tags: graphics, video, performance, 3d, download-speed

How do I improve the graphics for videos and 3D uses? I want to do it with software, and I'm hoping there's a way to increase graphics without compromising performance, or even making it better. Overclocking is not an option.

I'm on Ubuntu 21.04, and the reason why I'm not asking somewhere else is because I would like Ubuntu software. Also, would changing to KDE/XFCE help? I'm using GNOME 3.

My computer is an Intel Core i3 4020y, Integrated Graphics, 4 GB RAM. Not pretty, but it's all I have.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting...  If hardware performance could be improved with software, don't you think software devs would write their software to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by "improve the graphics" and "increase graphics"? What software are you using to display the "videos and 3D uses"? What else is your system doing?

Comment: Integrated Graphics are what they are. "Also, would changing to KDE/XFCE help? I'm using GNOME 3." KDE no, it likely more heavy than gnome.  XFCE: yes but also try Ubuntu Budgie. But don't expect graphics improvements: both the card AND the driver are always the same one. You can expect general performance improvements.

Comment: @waltinator - I just want faster graphics and better video/3D rendering.

Comment: @Rinzwind - OK. I'll try XFCE.

Comment: I was hoping for a setting like Windows's "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering" option... @Nmath / everyone else on Ubuntu.